# Is there a way to calc the mean of an dataframe for a column stepwise?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, lambda, statistics

is there a way to calc the mean of a df column stepwise. For example I have a df called data with 50 rows and I want to create a plot which shows the mean on the y axis and the number of samples on the x axis. So i need to know the mean of the first value in my column, then the mean of the first two values in my column and so on. Tried to do it with a lamda expression but failed.

Any one an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.expanding.html) and [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mean.html) to calculate your mean cumulatively:

**example**

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.arange(1, 50)})

data['cumulative_mean'] = data['col1'].expanding().mean()
```

[out]

```
    col1  cumulative_mean
0      1              1.0
1      2              1.5
2      3              2.0
3      4              2.5
4      5              3.0
..   ...              ...
44    45             23.0
45    46             23.5
46    47             24.0
47    48             24.5
48    49             25.0

[49 rows x 2 columns]
```

---

To plot, you could use:

```
data.index += 1
data['cumulative_mean'].plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With rolling windows you can do this realy easy. Here one example for 3 values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a'], data=np.arange(1,100))
df['a'].rolling(3).mean()
```

You can change the rolling window size in loop. 
Further infromation you can look into the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html).